# Which Infinity Stones have we seen so far in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, infinity-stones

Currently, the Marvel Cinematic Universe is setting up Thanos for later films, a mad Titan who is supremely powerful thanks to the Infinity Gauntlet, a device worn on the hand that is powered by 6 Infinity Stones or Infinity Gems.

In the comics, these are listed as;

- the **Power Gem**, which increases the user's physical power,
- the **Mind Gem**, which increases the user's psychic and mental abilities,
- the **Soul Gem**, which allows the user to control the free will of others,
- the **Space Gem**, which allows the user to travel through space,
- the **Time Gem**, which gives the user control over time, and
- the **Reality Gem**, which gives the user total control of reality.

So far, we have seen 4 of these stones in the MCU, in varying forms.

Very mild spoilers for *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*, *Thor: The Dark World* and *Guardians of the Galaxy* below.

> - In *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* we see the Tesseract is the Space Gem and that Loki's Staff contains what could soon turn out to be either the Mind Gem or the Soul Gem (This was later confirmed to be the Mind Gem in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*)
> - *In Thor: The Dark World* we see that the Aether is one of the Infinity Stones
> - In *Guardians of the Galaxy* we see that the mysterious orb contains one of the Infinity Stones.
>
> However, both the Purple Infinity Gem seen in *Guardians of the Galaxy* and the Aether in *Thor: The Dark World* appear to fulfill the role of the Power Gem.

So my question is - **which of these items in the films match the Gem in question, and what is the function of the other?**

Comment: At the risk of exposing spoilers, on this point — “we see the Tesseract is the Space Gem and that Loki's Staff contains the Soul Gem” — I’d agree that they seem similar to your description of those Infinity Gems from the comics, but they’re never actually described as such. The thing in Loki’s staff hasn’t even been called an Infinity Stone yet.

Comment: The fourth paragraph of this article (spoilers for *Guardians*) sounds like it gets confirmed by a character in *Guardians*: http://www.vulture.com/2014/06/thanos-guardians-of-the-galaxy-infinity-stones-josh-brolin.html But I haven’t seen the film, so I don’t know.

Comment: @alexwlchan You might want to put that as an answer, it sounds about right. Kind of makes sense with the Scarlet Witches reality bending powers now as well, if red is the colour of reality.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's an assumption, but I can't imagine a situation in which the Tesseract is not the Space Gem and the Soul Gem is not in Loki's staff. Until there is evidence to the contrary, I'll stick with it.

Comment: Prior to GotG, while stones have exhibited similar abilities to the stones, none of them have been clearly identified as "The XXX Stone", just that they ARE Infinity Stones. I don't know if that's changed as of last night.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: they haven’t really linked specific powers to each stone yet in the movies though. They seem like they’ve used them as generally-powerful McGuffins. They might be happy with that simpler level of detail in the films.

Comment: And I did see *Guardians* last night, but I didn’t pay enough attention to the Collector scene. They definitely do outline the fact that there are six Infinity Stones. They don’t mention that the Collector is in possession of the Aether from Thor 2.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well Loki's staff could control peoples free will, and the Tesseract was used to open portals between one point in space and another, so they seem like direct references to the powers that the Infinity Gems have to me. The Aether makes sense as the Reality Gem as Malekith was trying to end the universe in Thor: The Dark World, and the McGuffin in Guardians was explicitly named as the Power Gem according to the article linked in alexwlchan's comment.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43748/infinity-gems-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe?rq=1 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53853/is-the-gem-in-lokis-staff-an-infinity-stone?rq=1

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The Tesseract is confirmed to be the Space stone.  Which stone the Aether is hasn't been confirmed.  And there's no confirmation that Loki's staff has a stone yet.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: “the Tesseract was used to open portals between one point in space and another” — so was the Aether in Thor 2. Thor ended up riding the London Underground. Good times.

Comment: @Keen: ah yes, Word of Feige: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43755/440

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That wasn't the Aether opening portals, that was the Convergence.

Comment: @Keen: oh! My bad.

Comment: Dr. Strange is a strong contender for the Time gem (aka the Eye of Agamotto)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Mild spoiler warning.  I'm dropping spoilers from all over the MCU, up to and including *Doctor Strange*.

We've seen 5 confirmed Infinity Stones as of the release of *Doctor Strange*:

1. Tesseract - [The Space Stone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43755/1027).  From *Captain America: The First Avenger* and *Avengers*.
2. Aether - [The Reality Stone](http://www.craveonline.com/entertainment/film/interviews/852437-exclusive-interview-kevin-feige-on-the-infinity-stones-civil-war-and-more-marvel-studios/3).  From *Thor: The Dark World*
3. Unnamed Purple Stone from the Orb of Morag - Power Stone, [as confirmed](https://twitter.com/jamesgunn/status/496012832106749952) by *Guardians* director James Gunn.  From *Guardians of the Galaxy*.
4. The gem in Loki's staff - *Avengers: Age of Ultron* revealed that the gem is encasing the yellow Mind Gem.
5. [The Eye of Agamotto](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/29/doctor-strange-benedict-cumberbatch-powers) -  Time Stone. Confirmed as an Infinity Stone in *Doctor Strange*, and clearly maniuplates Time.

Comment: That pretty much confirms that the Aether is the Reality gem, correct?

Comment: Also, I would say that Loki's staff is more likely to be the Soul Gem than the Mind Gem as it is not enhancing Loki's psychic or mental abilities, it is allowing him to control the free will of others. Keep in mind that we have actually seen Adam Warlocks cocoon in the after-credits scene on Thor: The Dark World and both during and in the after-credits scene of Guardians of the Galaxy, so that could well be a hint for later - or alternatively, a reference to the character so that comic fans don't feel robbed. And keep in mind that Marvel are not afraid to deviate from the comics.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Per *Agents of SHIELD*, psychics don't exist in this universe, or they've never come in contact with Earth.  So enhancing 'psychic and mental abilities' makes less sense than simple mind control.  The Soul Gem in the comics likes to consume souls, is sentient, and has a pocket universe inside it.  Does that sound at all like Loki's staff?  Seemed like it didn't consume souls, it was easy to control, and didn't have a pocket universe that we saw.

Comment: All Infinity Stones http://bitcast-a-sm.bitgravity.com/slashfilm/wp/wp-content/images/ZZ73E85911.jpg

Comment: When was Orb of Morag displayed in MCU other than *Guardians of the Galaxy*?

Comment: I think it would be cool if the Eye of Agamotto - seen in Odin's vault during Thor and sure to appear in Dr. Strange - is the Time Stone. After all, it allows Strange to see anywhere in time.

Comment: A recording of the conference found its way online. The video does not *explicitly* state that Loki's staff contained a gem, but it is **heavily** implied. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8lUCbRi6QQ&list=UU_yLSDUCvWYbn4XN-HbDflQ

Comment: I think the Aether is the Soul Gem. Quote from Odin: "It seeks out host bodies, drawing strength from their life-force". Malekith uses the Convergence to do what he wants; the Gem is just a sort of power source (The movie is pretty vague) In Greek mythology, the name Aether means "soul of the world". Also, at the end of Guardians of the Galaxy, Adam Warlock's cocoon is open. It's not a far stretch to think he escaped and took the Aether/Soul Gem. The Reality Gem is a perfect fit for Doctor Strange. Guardians 2 could involve a time travel storyline using the Time Gem. Then we'll have seen all 6

Comment: @Dennis_E Great catch on the Aether potentially being the Soul Gem.

Comment: It could be possible for Hydra to be using Loki's staff as the source of Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch's powers which could make it the Reality Stone, or the Mind Gem (perhaps by unlocking certain dormant parts of their minds where their abilities come from) of course that's all speculation until the films hit the theaters.

Comment: Update: on May 1st, it was finally confirmed that the Aether is indeed the Reality Stone. So any theories about it being the Soul Stone or anything else are debunked :( In this interview, Kevin Feige says that the only Stones unaccounted for are Time and Soul. Since the other 3 are known, that leaves Reality for the Aether. http://www.craveonline.com/entertainment/film/interviews/852437-exclusive-interview-kevin-feige-on-the-infinity-stones-civil-war-and-more-marvel-studios/3

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Possible Spoilers

> I believe that the Aether in **Thor: The Dark World** is the Reality gem, seeing as Malekith wants to remove the light from the world. The Tesseract from **Captain America: The First Avenger** and **The Avengers/Avengers Assemble** is the Space gem, because it is used to create a wormhole in "Space" to allow the Chitauri to enter Earth. The gem in Loki's staff is the Soul gem, seeing as he used it to controls Hawkeye's free will. And in **Guardians of the Galaxy**, the Purple stone is the Power gem, because it is to powerful for the sentients to control, and it is what one would need to destroy an entire planet! The only other gems we need now are the Time gem and the Mind gem.

Answer (score 2):

Every stone has been confirmed and accounted for with the release of *Avengers: Infinity War*. In order of first appearance:

- **Space**, in the **Tesseract**, first seen in *Captain America: The First Avenger*
- **Mind**, in the **Sceptre**, first seen in *The Avengers*
- **Reality**, the **Aether**, first seen in *Thor: The Dark World*
- **Power**, in the **Orb**, first seen in *Guardians of the Galaxy*
- **Time**, in the **Eye of Agamotto**, first seen in *Doctor Strange*
- **Soul**, first seen in *Avengers: Infinity War*

Notably changed from the comics (as seen in everyone's assumptions before it was confirmed) it is the Mind stone that "allows the user to control the free will of others" among other things, while the Soul stone has unclear abilities.

Answer (score -1):

it was recently confirmed from director james gunn that the cocoon displayed in the collectors collection post credit thor 2 as well as gotg is infact adam warlocks cocoon.  if im not mistaken warlock bares the soul gem in the comics.  since we have yet to witness two of the six gems in the mcu, i would think that the soul gem could be ruled out as a possibility for the ones we have seen thus far. my research has led me to believe that the following gems can be matched with what we have seen so far in the films:

tesseract - space gem (dementional gateway as seen in avengers)
loki staff - mind gem (controls hawkeye/selvig in avengers)
aether - reality gem (can manipulate matter/ changes malekith's physical form)
ronan stone - power gem (um ya, when fused to his mallet becomes devistatingly powerful)

Thus we are left with soul and time.  As stated above I believe warlocks coming will see the soul gem.  As for the time gem I am not sure.  Perhaps Ultron or Ant-Man will give us some answers.

Fingers crossed warlock makes his grand enterance soon, baring the soul gem upon his glorious glorious forehead.

Comment: The Soul Gem ruled out? On the contrary, Warlock's cocoon appearing is more evidence to me that the Aether is in fact the Soul Gem. In the post-credits scene of Thor: The Dark World, the cocoon and the Aether are seen together in the same shot. When Warlock is introduced, the Aether will simply be inside him, just as it was inside Jane Foster and inside Malekith.

Comment: It's not Warlock's cocoon: http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=58710

Comment: “Bears” the Soul gem, as in holds it.

Answer (score -3):

The answers here are excellent. I concur with many of your assertions... Note that the colors of the objects in other forms have nothing to do with the colors of the actual gems except in one case.

- The Aether can only be the Reality Gem because of the abilities that have been attributed to it, namely the ability to alter all reality to suit it's wielder.
- The Tesseract is clearly the Space Gem. This requires no explanation.
- The Morag stone is the Power Gem. Only the lack of imagination on the part of its wielders kept the movie going, as any of them could easily have destroyed a planet with it. Easily.
- Loki's staff bears the Mind Gem, the only stone actually seen in its gem form, and the correct color. This is actually pretty obvious considering the scope of Loki's abilities (trickery and mind control). To be honest, though, I am a little shaky on this one. Would Loki not be FAR MORE POWERFUL if he was aware he was holding the Mind Gem?

The Soul and Time stones have yet to be seen, but do not doubt they will be soon.